# React Native Error: Redefinition of RCTMethodInfo after installing the plugin

Tags: ios, react-native, react-native-ios

I opened a new react-native project (latest version V0.49) and after installing the plugin react-nfc-manager,
I'm trying to run on ios with XCode 9 (simulators I test:IPHONE 6,7,7s IOS 11) it failed with error:
[image]

when I run on android it works fine.

Answer (score 13):

If this issue is being caused by a third party package, this can be fixed by searching for `#import "RCTBridgeModule.h"` in the third party library you are trying to use (in the file NameOfLibrary.h) and replace it with `#import <React/RCTBridgeModule.h>`.

Answer (score 4):

okay I found solution.
to change the order of the imports

```
     #if __has_include(<React/RCTBridgeModule.h>)
     #import <React/RCTBridgeModule.h>
     else
     #import "RCTBridgeModule.h"
     #endif
```

Comment: How exactly do you "change the order of the imports" using preprocessor directives, does this go in the .swift file, somewhere else?

Comment: yes, search for file called RCTBridgeModule I guess and then edit there

Comment: Typically the problem comes in a plugin project e.g. RNBluetoothState in my case. Editing the header there such as RNBluetoothState.h and replacing the import for RCTBridgeModule.h fixes the issue. Remember to add a # before the else statement. Its missing above. Can someone mark this as accepted answer ?

Comment: I think there is a typo. It's #else